# Can I specify which split-screen to display the actvitiy by startActivity in Android?

Tags: android

Suppose my application goes into split screen mode and is displayed on the top half of the screen.

I am now using `startActivity` to launch the settings activity. Can I specify that the settings activity is displayed on the bottom half of the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge you cannot do that with the stock Android. I saw some other posts in that regards claiming, i.e. Samsung's version of the Android let you control target of newly opened apps do that (IIRC it was about apps, not specific activities though), yet it was just Samsung specific.